# How would i create a realistic coat material for a horse model of mine?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm wondering how I could make a more realistic material for my horse:

[image: horse]

So far it's just an image mapped on to a diffuse shader. I want a more realistic coat. Also, I was messing around with hair particles, but couldn't get a realistic mane and tail. I've tried so many things for both of these, but I cant get it right. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I suggest you discard the materials on your horse completely. You should add a bunch of particle systems instead. Trust me, when you add a hair particle system it will look a lot more realistic.

Comment: Okay. What should I try, though? I've tried, like, countless particle systems, and nothing worked right. What should I do for this?

Comment: Have you tried using multiple particle systems put together with weight painting?

Comment: Don't know how to use weight painting, but I've tried combining particle systems. Still no idea what to do.

Comment: I figured out weight painting, watched a 2 hour tutorial, still wont work correctly

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar problem; I need to render a horse in Blender Render for work, and the best thing I've found so far is to add noise to your texture, and then use the noise layer as a bump map. With horses, I've found, having good definition of the muscles on the body really helps a lot.  Alas that's something I'm still working on. [image]

Comment: I still have no idea what to do.